# Phonegap image upload fail to upload

Tags: php, javascript, cordova, file-transfer

I am follow [this](http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap) tutorial for uploading images to a server using Phonegap. The data gets sent to the server but fails to upload. This is the response I get when I try to upload a picture to my server.

[image: Response]

here is my php code

```
<?php
  header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
  print_r($_FILES);
  $new_image_name = "image.jpg";
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/products/".$new_image_name);
?>
```

and here is my function to run the whole thing on my app

```
    function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";

        options.params = params;
        options.chunkedMode = false;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, "http://clubbedin.clanteam.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
    }

    function win(r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
        alert(r.response);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " = error.code);
    }
```

Here is the structure for the server
[image: directory]

Comment: The directory you're trying to move to isn't correct - `/products/` looks like it's at the root of the server, which I suspect isn't the case.

Comment: @andrewsi the /products/ is in my root. I will add a picture to the the post of my directory structure

Comment: What are the permissions set, in that case? Can the web user write to it?

Comment: @andrewsi ... I have no idea, I'm using some free hosting service currently, I don't know how to set the permissions on that :I

Comment: If you can get SSH access, then it's just a case of `chmod a+w` in the right directory. Otherwise, you might have to check with the webhost.

Comment: @andrewsi I figured out how to set the permissions and I made it so the web user can write to it and it still won't work!

Comment: I think it's because the path is wrong, in that case. `/products/` might be at the root when _you_ log in, but the _web user_ might have a different root. It's worth checking, at least - if you upload a PHP file containing just `getcwd()` or `dirname(__FILE__)`, they should show you what PHP thinks the path is.

Comment: @andrewsi so would the code just be `<?php
getcwd()
?>`

Comment: Ah, actually, you'll need to echo it out: `<?php echo(getcwd()); ?>` (I should have read the docs better) - `dirname` is the same.

Comment: @andrewsi alright, trying now

Comment: Feel free to add that as an answer and accept it when you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the path is wrong, in that case. /products/ might be at the root when you log in, but the web user might have a different root. It's worth checking, at least - if you upload a PHP file containing just echo(getcwd()); they should show you what PHP thinks the path is. - @andrewsi

Comment: Hi, where to put that file containing echo(getcwd()); in that upload directory?